# Tib RV - listing all the processes that are publishing to a given topic

Tags: java, tibco-rv

We have RV messaging systems publishing and receiving messages.Recently some underlying jars were upgraded - these are serialization jars used by all publishers and subscribers. However , it seems that ***some*** of the publishers are still referencing old versions of the serialization jars and therefore the receivers fail when trying to deserialize received messages.

Obviously restarting these publisher services should fix the problem. However , how do I identify **all** publishers using a particular topic to send messages to ? There must be some RV admin way of listing all the processes that are publishing to a given topic ?

Comment: all Tib RV Experts - please help !

Answer (score 0):

I just gave a similar answer on another question:

There is a really great tool for this called [Rai Insight](http://www.raitechnology.com/prod-rai-insight.php)

Basically what it can do is to sit on a box and silently listen all the multicast data and represent statistics even in real time. We used it to monitor traffic flow spikes with just few seconds delay.

It can give you traffic statistics braked down by multicast group, service number or even sending machine. Traffic flow peak/average, retransmission rate peak/average. All you can think of.

It will also give you per-service per-topic information.